# Adding additional names to a category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

Strange question which is typically against how Wordpress works but I'm wanting to add additional names to a category, almost like a "also known as".

So might have "Tech talk" as what the category is called but wanting to add "Bob Billy" (for example) as what the category can also be known as. I know about sub categories and this isn't what I mean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress categories, have description. you can use the description and show it anywhere on your blog/website. this is the case where you have just one alternative for each category and not more.
According to [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description):

```
 <?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>
```

> Returns the description of a category defined in the category settings screen for the current category (Posts > Categories).

Please let me know if it fits your needs, or I will hand you another way to acomplish that :)